# Can you create high-energy photons using multiple low-energy photons?

Tags: optics, photons, laser, crystals, photon-emission

I heard once that with a special crystal it's possible to "convert" somehow two green photons to a ultraviolet one and that some UV-lasers are based on this fact.  Is this right, and even more important:  Does anyone have a keyword I can use for some additional research?  My (german-language-based) research only led to some similar effects.

Comment: I believe so: try searching non-linear upconversion crystal.

Comment: Thanks!! (It seems to me that the "non-linear" isn't necessary)

Comment: The term you are looking for is **high harmonic generation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an effect called harmonic generation where two photons of similar wavelength are combined together into a single higher wavelength one in a nonlinear optical crystal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation

The effect is used in DPSS 532nm green lasers for converting IR light from an ND:YaG crystal into green light by using passing the IR light into an KTP crystal.

There also exists a process called photon upconversion whereby multiple photons of lesser wavelength are absorbed to produce a photon of shorter wavelength

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_upconversion

As for key-words for research,
nonlinear optics, harmonic generation, photon upconversion,

Comment: Thanks!! This works too!